# NamedQuery select returns List<Object>. How to obtain value from Object

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a select statement that goes into two table and obtain ids from each table. Here is my pseudo code:

Table 1 (study) has study_id

Table 2 (image) has image_id

```
NamedNativeQuery(name = "test", query = "select study.study_id, image.image_id from study study, image image where image_id=:imageId and study_id=:studyId")
```

In my code, I have:

```
Query query = getSession().getNamedNativeQuery("test");
query.setParameter(STUDY_ID, studyId);
query.setParameter(IMAGE_ID, imageId);
List result = query.getResultList(); //result is List<Object>
```

result is list of Object, where each Object has two values, one study_id and one image_id.

How do I extract these information from Object? What is the best approach to do this?

Comment: Cast to `Object[]` and cast each element in the array to its proper type (`Long` or whatever)?

Comment: Cast Object in the list to Object[]?

Comment: That is correctomundo. Then at least if you get a `ClassCastException` it'll tell you what the real class is, so you'll know what to cast them into.

Comment: Just so you know, you can use HQL for this purpose as well. HQL supports cross joins and joins between entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@SqlResultSetMapping` with `@ConstructorResult` in the following way:

```java
public class StudyImageIds {

    private final Long studyId;

    private final Long imageId;

    public StudyImageIds(Long studyId, Long imageId) {
        this.studyId = studyId;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    public Long getStudyId() {
        return studyId;
    }

    public Long getImageId() {
        return imageId;
    }
}

// ...

@NamedNativeQuery(
   name = "test",
   query = "select "
         + "  study.study_id as std_id, image.image_id as img_id "
         + "from study study, image image "
         + "where image_id = :imageId and study_id = :studyId",
   resultSetMapping = "study_image_ids_dto"
)
@SqlResultSetMapping(
   name = "study_image_ids_dto",
    classes = @ConstructorResult(
        targetClass = StudyImageIds.class,
        columns = {
            @ColumnResult(name = "std_id"),
            @ColumnResult(name = "img_id")
        }
    )
)
```

and then use it:

```java
List<StudyImageIds> studyImageIds = session.getNamedQuery("test")
  .setParameter(STUDY_ID, studyId)
  .setParameter(IMAGE_ID, imageId)
  .list();
```

IMHO this is much more safer and elegant than types casting. See further details in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-scalar-named-queries).